# How to echo/print the last iteration in this loop

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

cat /usr/local/nagios/libexec/std_filesystem.txt | while read line
do

if [ -d $line ]; then
    file_system_name="-p $line"
new_file+=" $file_system_name"
check_filesystem="$new_file"
fi
done
echo $new_file

std_filesystem.txt has the following content
/usr/jboss
/www
/www/archive
/www/logs/jboss
/www/logs/heapdump
/opt
/opt/splunk
/opt/splunk/logs
/opt/udeploy
/www-pri1
/tmp
```

I want to be able to print out just the last iteration of this loop. Let's say, only /www /tmp /opt exists, I want the echo to be "-p /www -p /tmp -p /op". Thanks for helping guys

Comment: how can you want to print three values and only the last at the same time?

Comment: basically, I want to write a script to check if these filesystem exists, so i can add it to Nagios monitoring.

Comment: they're filesystems? or directories? or just files? or does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

To do as asked you need only change `+=` to `=`.

Rather than appending to an existing value for every true case found, if you *overwrite* the last true case with a new one each time then when the loop ends the last true value will be the only one in `$new_file`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me mikeserv

Comment: @HaiLe - that's unfortunate - and also a little unhelpful. please elaborate?